# How to take the value of a clicked event on another page or div in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to echo the value of the clicked event in another `div`, but I don't know what logic should I use for that in function `changecolor()`.

```
<fieldset class="step">
                <legend>Roti</legend>
                <?php
                $qu = mysql_query("select * from submenu WHERE menu_id=33") or die(mysql_error());
                while($f = mysql_fetch_array($qu)){
                ?>
                <p>
                    <label for="name" onclick="changeColor(this)"><?php echo $f['submenu']; ?></label>
                    <script>
                        function changeColor(obj){
                            obj.style.color = "red";
                        }

                    </script>
                    </p>
                <?php } ?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I just want that particular piece of code to be put to echo the clicked value in that change color function

Comment: you want to echo color in div or label text in a div or something else

Comment: i want to echo the text in label @YatinKhullar

Comment: which text will you please elaborate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript's `innerHtml` method like this.

```
<p>
    <label for="name" onclick="changeColor(this)"><?php echo 'Somename'; ?></label>
</p>
    <div id="target_div"></div>
    <script>
    function changeColor(obj){
        obj.style.color = "red";
        var selected_val = obj.innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('target_div').innerHTML= selected_val;
    }
    </script>
```

Edit: To show all selected labels' text in the div, just append it like below

```
<p>
<label for="name" onclick="changeColor(this)"><?php echo 'Somename 1'; ?></label>
<label for="name" onclick="changeColor(this)"><?php echo 'Somename 2'; ?></label>
<label for="name" onclick="changeColor(this)"><?php echo 'Somename 3'; ?></label>
<label for="name" onclick="changeColor(this)"><?php echo 'Somename 4'; ?></label>
</p>
<div id="target_div"></div>
<script>
function changeColor(obj){
    obj.style.color = "red";
    var selected_val = obj.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('target_div').innerHTML=document.getElementById('target_div').innerHTML+" "+selected_val;
}
</script>
```

Comment: ok but can you please give me an example in this case as i am very new in this field...thanks in advance

Comment: ok i have done it and its working fine but it is showing only the last selected value.What if i want to append the newly  selected values with previous one and display all the values that are selected...

Comment: Do you want show all the clicked label values in a div or just append it to the end of the div?

Comment: i want to just show all the clicked values in another div

Comment: Edited my answer. It will append the label to the div when you clicks on it

Answer (score -1):

use hidden input field. on click of button save that value by id of input field.
    $('#id_of_hidden_input').val(value_to_save);

now get that value on another page using POST.